# Howe to stop things moving on the page?

Tags: css

I have created an animated navigation bar.

Code is :

```
#nav ul li a:hover{
    color: #000033;
    background-color:#bcbceb;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 0 1em 1em 0;       
    transition-property: width, color, background-color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in, ease in; 
    -moz-transition-property: width, color, background-color;
    -moz-transition-duration:  0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in, ease in; 
    -webkit-transition-property: width, color, background-color;
    -webkit-transition-duration:  0.5s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in, ease in; 
}
```

This is on the left hand side of the page. When each nav link moves to the right, it moves whatever content I have on the right to the right, rather than being in a fixed postion.
I have tried position:fixed; but it doesn’t appear to work.

Here is the HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><h3><a href="index.html">Home</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="construction.html">Construction</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="it.html">I T Dept</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="web.html">Websites</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="cf.html">Company Forms</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="smf.html">Site Management Forms</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="phonebook.html">Phone Book</a></h3></li>
</ul>​
```

[`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/4BRMC/)

```
#content 
{
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid #000033;
    padding:50px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: position: absolute; maybe?

Comment: Can you post some other details

Comment: Sure - it is very difficult for me to explain. I have a navigation bar on the left and content on right after you click on each button on the nav bar. The animated nav bar buttons when clicked make the content on the right move - it is very frustrating

Comment: what are you using `asp.net`? `html` designing?

Comment: sorry i am having trouble putting html code in

Comment: You're going to need to provide us with more details. We need to see a working example of the problem, a detailed description of what is expected to happen, and some details about where you are seeing the problem (web browser, operating system, etc.). Then we can help!

Comment: I am having trouble editing the css so u can see the problem

Comment: Will you post a image or add your codings in this jsbin http://jsbin.com/ugikuf/1/edit

Comment: I have added my code into jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the position:relative to your div attribute and then add the position eg. top:10px or left 10px, depending on where u want it to be, u can also use the "bottom" atribute to position it..

Comment: I did what u said and the box covers the entire width of the page

Comment: Cant do anything til i get home which is ina few hours - please do not close this post